# Prove $(\forall n\in\Bbb N)(\exists N\in\Bbb N)(\forall m\in\Bbb N)\left(m\ge N \to \left|\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^m - e\right|<\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, exponential-function

> Prove that

- $(\forall n\in\Bbb N)(\exists N\in\Bbb N)(\forall m\in\Bbb N)\left(m\ge N \to \left|\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^m - e\right|<\frac{1}{n}\right)$.
- $(\forall x\in\Bbb Q)(\exists n\in\Bbb N)(\forall N\in\Bbb N)(\exists m\in\Bbb N)\left(m\ge N \;\&\; \left|\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^m - x\right|\ge\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

So I got this problem from my professor. For the first part, I've tried to wrote $m$ as $n$ or $n+1$ (because $m$ was supposedly greater than or equal to $N$, which was a part of $n$), but still can't find a solution. And for the second part, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: You can learn MathJax from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: what is your definition of $e$ ?

Comment: It's euler number

Comment: The first part of the question from the professor just wants you to prove that the sequence $$1 + (1/m))^m$ converges to $e$. It is a problem from elementary calculus, not from mathematical logic. The proof may not be obvious, depending on your definition of $e$, but it is covered in many texts.

Comment: So how do I prove that it's less than (1/n)?

Comment: If you have a proof that works for all $\varepsilon>0$ (as is ordinarily the case with convergence proofs), then it will work in particular when $\varepsilon=\frac1n$.

Comment: Isn't that how $e$ is defined? What definition are you working with for $e$.